# MvvmCross - Is it allowed to change Services namespace name?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I wouldn't like to have a `KittensBg.Core.Services` namespace to place the database and related stuff. Because the "services" word also would be used in `KittensBg.Droid.Services` (to store backgrounding/service classes). Can I change it?

I would like to move the models (as `Kitten` and `KittenShop` classes) to `KittenBg.Core.Model`. And also move the `KittenGenesisService` to `KittensBg.Core.Messaging`.  Is it OK? Is the 'Services' namespace a hardcoded requirement in MvvmCross?

And the last thing, I don't want to suffix all those 'service' classes with the 'Service' word. How can I initialize the Core to keep its dependency injection working in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the 'Services' namespace a hardcoded requirement in MvvmCross?

No - it's just the name used in the default `App.cs` and in the examples I produce.

There's a wiki article which may assist with this - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control

This includes a section on "[Bulk Registration by Convention](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control#bulk-registration-by-convention)" which includes:

> The choice of name ending here - Service - and the choice to use Lazy singletons are only personal conventions.  If you prefer to use other names or other lifetimes for your objects you can replace this code with a different call or with multiple calls like:

```
    CreatableTypes()
        .EndingWith("SingleFeed")
        .AsInterfaces()
        .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
    CreatableTypes()
        .EndingWith("Generator")
        .AsInterfaces()
        .RegisterAsDynamic();
    CreatableTypes()
        .EndingWith("QuickSand")
        .AsInterfaces()
        .RegisterAsSingleton();
```

Comment: Nice! The "register as dynamic" method means that those classes are going to be plain non-singleton objects, right?